# OSX Using Beyond Compare as git difftool

Tags: git, macos, beyondcompare, git-difftool

When trying to launch Beyond Compare using git, I get this error:

> The diff tool bc3 is not available as 'bcompare'
>
> fatal: external diff died, stopping at plugins/PushPlugin.m

Set up diff tool:

```
$ git config --global diff.tool bc3
```

Try to compare directory:

```
$ git difftool plugins

Viewing (1/2): 'plugins/PushPlugin.m'
Launch 'bc3' [Y/n]: y
```

Comment: Note, that `bcompare` is not suitable for git diff, as git creates temporary files for one or both of the sides and deletes them after difftool returns, and `bcompare` returns immediately. `bcomp` does the job.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Launch Beyond Compare, go to the Beyond Compare menu and run Install Command Line Tools.

Comment: Great, I don't think they mentioned this on there website.

Answer (score 3):

According to official website: [Scooter Software: Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs_osx)

Launch Beyond Compare, go to the Beyond Compare menu and run Install Command Line Tools.

Diff
In a terminal:

```
git config --global diff.tool bc3
```

To launch a diff using Beyond Compare, use the command:  git difftool file.ext

Merge Pro only
In a terminal:

```
git config --global merge.tool bc3
git config --global mergetool.bc3.trustExitCode true
```

To launch a 3-way merge using Beyond Compare, use the command:  git mergetool file.ext